# What's better? Adding a comment? Or answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Is it better to answer the question or add the answer in a comment, for example [I added this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934512/rank-over-order-by-for-multiple-criterias#comment123623866_69934512) and then someone answered the same thing, should I've answered it?

While [here I've answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69975790/16019058) would it be better if it was in a comment?

Is it worth to rather answer for the reputation?

Comment: Answers for answers, comments for clarity and detail requests.

Comment: Your comment is better than the answer, but generally answers should be answers.

Comment: I find it amazing that this is the first time anybody has ever asked this SQL question in the history of Stack Overflow. Has there never been anybody else who needed to order their results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## If you want to answer, then *answer* the @!%$ question.

Don't comment when you mean to answer.

Comment: I hate this when people comment an answer, especially when they've done so while I'm writing basically the same thing as an answer.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, even here on Meta I noticed that my tendency was to write a comment instead of an answer.  So instead of shouting the example, I decided to become the example.

Comment: I can't answer this @!%$ question because it's closed :P.

Comment: But not if it is the 1000th duplicate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Imagine a world where you would have to repeat the same common sense things over and over again. Oh wait... that is the world we live in.

Answer (score 6):

Let me address this quote from your question:

> Is it worth to rather answer for the reputation?

No. Stack Overflow aims to build a high quality collection of narrow scoped questions and the answers to those questions. If you post content on Stack Overflow you do so with the intention to improve and extent that high quality collection of Q and A's.

There is no reputation in that equation. Never, ever do something on SO *for the reputation*. Other sites outside of the SE network happily cater for that.

Comment: Absolutely I didn't mean to ask if I should answer always just for reputation but when it's a basic answer like the `order by` if I should add it in the comment in a clarification way like I did, the question is if this is the right practice? Or maybe because it's an answer and probably the answer, if it's the right way to do to add the reputation in the picture? And I see you answer for this question, NO.

Comment: @Shmiel If it's "a basic answer like the `order by`" then *chances are* that it's already been answered. Probably more than once. SO has been active for over a decade - basic questions about long-standing technologies have largely been covered. Feel free to flag as a duplicate. Do not just dilute the knowledge further by scattering it more. Enough of this and in another decade we won't even have a repository of high quality questions an answers. Just a bunch of oft-repeated questions and answers with varying quality.

Comment: How can I search if that type of question is a duplicate in my 2 examples? What text for example should I search in the search bar?

Comment: @Shmiel "sql order by site:stackoverflow.com" from a search engine is a good start. On SO you start with "[sql] order by" and work from there. I did it and it turns out there is a tag [[tag:sql-order-by]] tag which can also help narrow down results. For the second one I'd start with "table name in quotes sq; site:stackoverflow.com" and see if anything relevant pops up.